# Are Google Chrome's suggestions encrypted?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ssl

Some of you might have noticed that Google has changed their search to [use SSL by default](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/google/google-search-gets-default-ssl-security/3407). I noticed that even if you set your search engine on Chrome to unsecured Google, the results are delivered via HTTPS.

I was wondering if the suggestions typed on the address bar are also sent via SSL. If not, how can I make them so?

[image]

I can [change the default search provider to Google SSL](http://www.mytechguide.org/7974/make-google-https-secured-ssl-search-default/), but then I lose the suggestions.

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question there. If you use Google SSL you lose suggestions.

Comment: @ThiagoM.: Your intuition is correct, but it's not *that* simple. Creating a custom search using Google without SSL also disables suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

I can't find any documentation the verifies this claim, but you can check it out yourself.

#### Test

1. If it's not already enabled and you don't have another firewall running, enable Windows Firewall.
2. Create a rule that blocks all outgoing TCP connections with remote port `80`.
3. Close all open TCP connections to Google IPs on port `80`.

   - An easy way to do this is closing all Chrome tabs.
   - If you have a connection monitor like [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html), you can close the connections manually.
4. Start typing in the omnibox.

#### Result

There will be no suggestions.

#### Conclusion

Suggestions don't use SSL.